# Weblogic configuration wizard fails to start

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have the Oracle Weblogic 12.1.3 and the installation went well and the server was starting successfully. But now It fails to start for some unknown reason. It had problems with the base domain that I created in the setup. So now I'm trying to set up a new domain. But the problem is that the configuration wizard fails to start. I've tried running it with Run as Administrator but the cmd just pops up and disappears. I tried to reinstall the Weblogic server from start and even that didn't solve the problem. The part where the configuration wizard starts I got the same issue. I've also tried running it from command prompt itself but the same thing happens. I have also tried this:

```
config.cmd -mode=console
```

and in the cmd it says

```
Files/Microsoft went wrong this time
```

and also running it in "text" mode like this

```
config.sh -mode=console
```

but it fails to start. and shows the following:

[image: the error message cmd window]

What could be the problem and the fix for this? I'm running Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some discrepancy in the `path` variable of the environmental variables. Re-arranged the path values and inserted/removed quotes from some values and added that path value containing `Files/Microsoft` int the end(which was added by Microsoft VS Code). This solved the problem.